# Who set the tasks for the Triwizard Tournament?

Tags: harry-potter, triwizard-tournament

We know that the Departments of International Magical Co-operation and Magical Games and Sports were working on the latest attempt to bring back the Triwizard Tournament, so I always assumed that they had set the tasks.

But on a re-read I noticed this:

> The instructions for the tasks the champions will face this year have already been examined by Mr Crouch and Mr Bagman

and

> We have worked hard over the summer to ensure that, this time, no champion will find himself or herself in mortal danger

which makes it sound like they had to work around pre-decided tasks, rather than making new (safer) ones up. I suppose their depts could have been working on it without them knowing the actual tasks but it seems unlikely. The champions are chosen by a 'central' authority, rather than the organisers, so perhaps the tasks are too.

Has JKR ever given any background to this? I know in *The Hunger Games* they have a box of pre-written 'conditions', and I was wondering if there was any evidence of something similar here.

Comment: If they're doing health and safety and overseeing that they still would have had to have done so whether it was a newly created task or a pre-decided one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That's true (although I have major doubts about whether blast-ended skrewts should have been allowed!). It's more the first quotation "the instructions for the tasks...have already been examined" that sounds like they were given them by somebody/thing else that I was questioning. The safety quotation was more for completeness/describing what the DMGS had been doing. I could remove it if it would make it clearer?